# Assign an object in a form

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a form which should print questions dynamically.  `Foo` has a `Field` object and a `Field Definition` object.  I want the `Field` to have its `fieldDefinition` assigned by the form.  All of the behind the scenes stuff works fine.

The below code works with assigning Strings and Longs in other scenarios.

Here's the line that's causing trouble:

```
<input th:type="hidden" th:field="*{fields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].fieldDefinition}" th:value="${fooViewModel.fields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].fieldDefinition}"/>
```

This is what it looks like when it renders in html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="com.blah.domain.FieldDefinition@fbb2e392" id="fields0.fieldDefinition" name="fields[0].fieldDefinition">
```

When I submit the form, no controller action is invoked, and the app simply redirects to the error page.

If it's impossible to actually do the assignment that way, please suggest other methods.  The only way I came up with is to have `Foo` use the `FieldDefinitionService` to do the assignment after being passed an ID. I don't that Domain class to have access to another Domain object's `Service`.

Thanks

Comment: Input type=hidden can only contain String values. com.blah.domain.FieldDefinition@fbb2e392 is the value of your fieldDefinition represented as a String (i.e. the value of fieldDefinition.toString() ). I don't get what you want to do so I can't help you much further, but I guess you could use something like th:field="*{fields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].fieldDefinition.id}"

Comment: I guess there is a `th:each` somewhere and a `form` tag. Can you post the entire fragment, please?

Comment: Thanks @PedroAffonso, can you recommend a JPA model to go along with that?  I almost feel like you'd have to create an extra service method just to align `fieldDefinintionId` with `field` every time you call it.  At that point it makes more sense to copy the attrs from `fieldDefinition` to `field` for each instance.  What do you think?

Answer (score -1):

Just an example: when you need to iterate a form inside an element that has a `th:each` attribute, you can use the following structure (so far, it's the only way that's working for me).

```
<tr th:each="rank, stat : ${ranks}">
    <td th:text="${rank.name}">This is static</td>
    <td th:text="${rank.description}">This is static</td>
    <td>
        <form th:action="@{/user/ranks/delete}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" th:value="${rank.id}"></input>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here `ranks` is a list of entities that have to be displayed on a `table` and, for each entity, there is a delete button associated to a form.

The controller method should be similar to the following fragment, the parameter is availabled with the name `id`:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View deleteRank(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "id") String rankId,
        @ModelAttribute("user") User user)
{
    Long id = Long.parseLong(rankId);

    // delete ...

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/user/ranks");
    return redirectView;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the question I'm trying to answer.  Thank you though.